# Minimisation problem obeying coupled inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, optimization, linear-programming, maxima-minima

I have a set of 4 two sided inequalities and 3 variables in the form

$ A[0] \le +Z + X \le B[0]$

$ A[1] \le +Z - X \le B[1]$

$ A[2] \le -Z + Y \le B[2]$

$ A[3] \le -Z - Y \le B[3]$

Where all A[j] < B[j], Ideally I would like to find a solution that satisfies these equations while minimising

$S = a |Z| + (1-a) (|X|+|Y|)$

with $0 \le a \le 1$, but I would settle for solutions with just a = 0 and a = 1.  I'm not really sure where to start with this sort of problem, do I derive lots of sets of equations based on the signs elements in A and B?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this via linear programming by introducing additional variables $X'$, $Y'$, and $Z'$ and constraints:
\begin{align}
X' &\ge X \\
X' &\ge -X \\
Y' &\ge Y \\
Y' &\ge -Y \\
Z' &\ge Z \\
Z' &\ge -Z \\
\end{align}
The new objective is to minimize $aZ'+(1-a)(X'+Y')$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm not sure if I understand the new variables as those inequalities can only be satisfied together if $X = Y = Z = 0$. 

Do I need to split this into 8 cases where  $X' \ge X , Y' \ge Y, Z' \ge Z$, or $X' \ge -X , Y' \ge Y, Z' \ge Z$,.. etc?

Comment: Those constraints do not force $X=Y=Z=0$. Instead they force $X’\ge |X|$, $Y’\ge |Y|$, and $Z’\ge |Z|$, and the objective drives those inequalities to equalities. You do not need any cases.

Comment: Oh sorry that's my mistake.  Certainly nice to remove the absolute values in the minimisation.